# How to pass phone and email to invocable method

Tags: apex, email, visual-flows, invocable-method, apex-variable

I have a visual flow from which I want to pass some person account info to an invocable method. It seems that when I use a phone and email field I can't assign them to my invocable class. Is this because the invocable class only accepts primitive values or is there a way around?

Apex

```
public class CreatePersonAccount{
    @InvocableMethod(label='Create Account' Description='Create an Account')
    public static List<methodOutputs> invokeThisMethod(List<methodInputs> request) {
        methodOutputs fo = new methodOutputs();
        system.debug( request);
        try{
            Id personAccountRecordTypeId =  Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('PersonAccount').getRecordTypeId();
            Account newPersonAccount = new Account();
            newPersonAccount.FirstName = request[0].FirstName ;
            newPersonAccount.LastName = request[0].LastName ;
            newPersonAccount.RecordTypeId = personAccountRecordTypeId;
            insert newPersonAccount;
            fo.DMLResult = 'Success' ;
        } catch(Exception e){
            fo.DMLResult = 'Error' ;
        }
        List<MethodOutputs> theResults = new List<MethodOutputs>();
        theResults.add(fo) ;
        return theResults;
    }
    //input details that come to apex from flow
    public class methodInputs{
        @InvocableVariable
        public String Initials;
        @InvocableVariable
        public String FirstName;
        @InvocableVariable
        public String Insertion;
        @InvocableVariable
        public String LastName;
        @InvocableVariable
        public string Phone;
        @InvocableVariable
        public String Email;
        @InvocableVariable
        public date Birthdate;
    }
    //output details which goes from apex to flow
    public class methodOutputs{
        @InvocableVariable
        public String test ;
        @InvocableVariable
        public String DMLResult ;
    } 
}
```

Comment: email and phone are stored as string primitives in back end, so that can't be the issue, what exact issue are you facing here?

Comment: @rahulgawale You can literally copy this class and check by adding a phone or email variable into a screen flow to an apex action and see this cannot be passed to the invocable.

Comment: Please [edit] and show the portions of the Flow (including relevant data elements) that you are trying to pass to the invocable apex

Comment: @Thomas I tried, it is working fine for me. Please add your flow screen shots

Comment: @rahulgawale did you used a the type phone or type email in your variable of the flow instead of text? With text of couse ther are no issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using a text field and do the validation trough regex apex. Below is my example:

```
emailRegex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9._|\\\\%#~`=?&/$^*!}{+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$';
```